# Breaking down Tensorflow performance with timeline and benchmarking

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, distributed

Using TF 0.12.1, we are trying to understand how the performance of Tensorflow breaks down. In particular, we are looking at the Inception-v3 model, and how long the forward pass step takes.

The first step we looked at was to run a benchmark on just in the inference step. To avoid queueing time, we set the training example to a constant tensor and run it through the inception model. The train method in the code is below

```
def train(dataset):
  """Train on dataset for a number of steps."""
  with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    # Create a variable to count the number of train() calls. This equals the
    # number of batches processed * FLAGS.num_gpus.
    global_step = tf.get_variable(
        'global_step', [],
        initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)

    # Calculate the learning rate schedule.
    num_batches_per_epoch = (dataset.num_examples_per_epoch() /
                             FLAGS.batch_size)
    decay_steps = int(num_batches_per_epoch * FLAGS.num_epochs_per_decay)

    # Decay the learning rate exponentially based on the number of steps.
    lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(FLAGS.initial_learning_rate,
                                    global_step,
                                    decay_steps,
                                    FLAGS.learning_rate_decay_factor,
                                    staircase=True)

    # Create an optimizer that performs gradient descent.
    opt = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(lr, RMSPROP_DECAY,
                                    momentum=RMSPROP_MOMENTUM,
                                    epsilon=RMSPROP_EPSILON)

    # Get images and labels for ImageNet and split the batch across GPUs.
    assert FLAGS.batch_size % FLAGS.num_gpus == 0, (
        'Batch size must be divisible by number of GPUs')
    split_batch_size = int(FLAGS.batch_size / FLAGS.num_gpus)
    num_classes = dataset.num_classes() + 1

    # Calculate the gradients for each model tower.
    tower_grads = []
    reuse_variables = None
    for i in xrange(FLAGS.num_gpus):
      with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
        with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % (inception.TOWER_NAME, i)) as scope:
          # Force all Variables to reside on the CPU.
          with slim.arg_scope([slim.variables.variable], device='/cpu:0'):
            # Calculate the loss for one tower of the ImageNet model. This
            # function constructs the entire ImageNet model but shares the
            # variables across all towers.
            image_shape = (FLAGS.batch_size, FLAGS.image_size, FLAGS.image_size, 3)
            labels_shape = (FLAGS.batch_size)
            images = tf.zeros(image_shape, dtype=tf.float32)
            labels = tf.zeros(labels_shape, dtype=tf.int32)

            logits = _tower_loss(images, labels, num_classes,
                               scope, reuse_variables)

          # Reuse variables for the next tower.
          reuse_variables = True

    # Build an initialization operation to run below.
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    # Start running operations on the Graph. allow_soft_placement must be set to
    # True to build towers on GPU, as some of the ops do not have GPU
    # implementations.
    sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
        allow_soft_placement=True,
        log_device_placement=FLAGS.log_device_placement))
    sess.run(init)

    # Start the queue runners.
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)

    for step in xrange(FLAGS.max_steps):
      start_time = time.time()
      loss_value = sess.run(logits)
      duration = time.time() - start_time
      examples_per_sec = FLAGS.batch_size / float(duration)
      format_str = ('%s: step %d, loss =(%.1f examples/sec; %.3f '
                      'sec/batch)')
      print(format_str % (datetime.now(), step,
                          examples_per_sec, duration))
```

For 8 GPUs, a batch size of 32, and 1 param server, we observe 0.44 seconds per logits operation which does the forward pass. However, when we run the timeline tool, we observe a much smaller inference time (see figure below). For the GPU runtime, observe that there is an initial burst followed by a break, followed by a longer GPU burst. We assume the initial burst is the forward pass while the second burst is the backpropagation.

[image]

If the initial burst really is the forward pass time, it is substantially less than 0.44 seconds. Can anyone explain the discrepancy between these results? Is it a mistake with the benchmarking app or is the timeline tool not capturing the full picture? Additionally, there are a couple of GPU operations before the first large burst that we cannot really explain. Any insight into this would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow has undergone a number of significant performance improvements since TF 0.12.1. If you are interested in solid performance numbers, please use the latest version of TensorFlow, or version 1.2 when it is released.

If you would like to work from a high-performance model as a starting point, I strongly recommend working from https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks which include an Inception-v3 model.

As for trying to understand the detailed performance of a single step, I recommend instrumenting the C++ TensorFlow runtime. (The overhead from within Python can be significant, and could introduce uncertainty in your measurements.)

Additionally, it's important to run the experiment a number of iterations to allow the system to "warm up" and fully initialize.

One thing to note: if you are trying to tune your model, be sure to avoid setting `allow_soft_placement=True`. For now, it's better to ensure that all operations you expect are truly placed on the GPUs. You can confirm by looking at the log output controlled by the `log_device_placement` parameter.